# Advanced Collections in Java?

Tags: java

To Understand the Collection Package Properly. The new API's which are to do the more advantage and comfortable of using Collections. for Example `ConcurrentHashMap` can able to load the data to the UI when the insertion performing to the map. like this Share Some Interesting Facts and Tutorials. To grow up our knowledge to the upcoming developer like me.

Comment: There's a language problem here. I don't understand what you're asking, if there's a question at all.

Comment: Share the innovative techniques or advantages of using Collection ?

Comment: I think he needs tutorial how to use advanced collection classes from Java

Comment: @nanda: i would need some interesting facts in collections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brian Goetz' [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://www.javaconcurrencyinpractice.com/) covers Nonblocking Concurrent Collections and explains how [Compare and Swap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap) low level instructions are used to implement thread-safe data structures achieving non-blocking thread-safety.

It actually covers the whole [High Level Concurrency API](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/highlevel.html) introduced since JSE5, but IMHO it is good book to have near your keyboard.